# SSIS packages 2005 & 2008 editable with what versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, ssis, bids

I know that in order to edit SSIS packages you need the same version of BIDS or Visual Studio.
With Visual Studio 2010 is there any change in the ability to open older SSIS packages or do I need to have VS2005 and VS2008 installed along side my VS2010 installation?

TIA
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2010 will not work with VS2005 and VS2008 SSIS packages.  You still must use the respective VS versions for your development.  You can have each VS version installed on your system.